# search replace does nothing

Tags: .net, vb.net, io, replace

I am trying to edit all txt files in a folder (textbox4). If it finds searched word (textbox2) it repleaces with other (textbox3). But code does nothing.

```
Dim mydir As String = TextBox4.Text
Dim savetxt As New List(Of String)
For Each txtfile As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(mydir, "*.txt") 
For Each line As String In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(txtfile)
If line.Contains(TextBox2.Text) Then
line.Replace(TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text)
End If
savetxt.Add(line)
Next
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(txtfile, savetxt.ToArray)
savetxt.Clear()
Next
```

Comment: This is not how StackOverflow works. First you'll have to show some effort and what [you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) so far and then we'll try to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`string.Replace()` returns the new value rather than modifying the existing instance. You need to store the result if it's needed:

```
line = line.Replace(TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Private Function GetFiles(Path As String) As String()
            Dim Files() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles(Path)
            Return Files
        End Function

Private Sub ProcessFiles(Files As String(), Find As String, Replace As String)
    Dim txt As String

    For Each file In Files
        txt = IO.File.ReadAllText(file)
        If txt.Contains(Find) = True Then
            IO.File.WriteAllText(file, txt.Replace(Find, Replace))
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

---

Then implement like this:

```
Private Sub Initate(Path As String, Find As String, Replace As String)
        'get the files paths
        Dim files() As String = GetFiles(Path)

        'find the text and replaces it
        ProcessFiles(files, Find, Replace)
    End Sub
```

To where [Find] , [Replace], and [Path] is the textbox.text